Any way to skip/automatically select the "show in conversations" setting (this folder/all mailboxes) in Outlook with VBA?
I am attempting to toggle the "show in conversations" folder setting in Outlook without user input. The setting itself can be turned on and off with the following, suggested here:
ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ShowInConversations")

However, this triggers a modal popup asking the user to select between "this folder" and "all mailboxes".
Is there any way to skip that modal dialog box, or have a selection be automatically selected via VBA scripting?

Try to set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView.ShowFullConversations to false.

That changes the settings, but it does not skip or dismiss the modal popup box.
